# Windows 8 to 8.1 Pro Upgrade SecureBoot Error

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, secure-boot

I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. I have an Alienware Aurora R4 with the latest BIOS firmware version, A09. Ever since I did the upgrade, I get a watermark on my desktop saying, "SecureBoot isn't configured correctly"...I would like to get rid of this watermark the correct way (not by hacking system DLLs). My BIOS shows me booting in UEFI mode, and I see that SecureBoot is actually disabled from there. I cannot enable SecureBoot, in either UEFI mode or Legacy Boot mode. Note, I can't even get Legacy Boot mode working without re-formatting my system which I really don't plan on doing, so my question is this...what has changed in the way Windows handles SecureBoot? As far as I can tell, I do not have SecureBoot enabled, and it is trying to tell me that it isn't configured correctly. Why does it even care to check if my BIOS doesn't have it on anyways?! Its so frustrating!

Comment: Lets start with what sort of partition you have MBR or GPT?

Comment: Disk 0 is GPT. Disk 1 is also GPT.

Comment: Got the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to hack my graphics cards in order to introduce a GOP partition which allowed my BIOS to hash its ROM for Secure Boot key creation, which, for a reason beyond my own knowledge, it did require. Maybe because its a hardware device that has a flashable ROM and the BIOS was programmed to check all hardware for consistency in order to avoid hardware malware. For more information, [I went through this process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qf3ft0iB5iY).

Answer (score 2):

I [asked this Microsoft](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Elevated-App-Turning-off-Tabbed-Browsing-Win-81-RTM#time=05m11s) and the answer was, that they show this watermark to make sure that OEMs don't release new systems without having SecureBoot turned on.

Comment: This doesn't make sense for me, since I have an "old" system by their definition, and its already disabled in the BIOS with no way to enable it. I'm shaking my head right now. This is completely unacceptable. Microsoft...how can you mess up on a Windows release this bad?

Comment: I'm also confused by this answer. I'll stay at Win8, here I'm not annoyed by this watermark.

Answer (score 1):

I have also this problem. And i have fixed the problem You can find your answer on this link: [Windows 8 to 8.1 Pro Upgrade SecureBoot Error](http://windowstechblog.nl/secureboot-juist-geconfigureerd-windows-8-1-pro)

Comment: This does not work for me. I cannot enable SecureBoot in my BIOS like you can.